# How to check the log of a service deployed in a pod of kubernetes, where the pod is at evicted state

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Normally to view logs of the service running in pod we use below command:

```
kubectl logs -f <pod_name>
```

but for the evicted pod, it doesn't work.
All I can see the overall pod health by running below command:

```
kubectl describe po <evicted_pod_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below command

```
kubectl logs my-pod -c my-container --previous
```

This dumps pod container logs (stdout, multi-container case) for a previous instantiation of a container

or

```
kubectl logs my-pod --previous
```

This dumps pod logs (stdout) for a previous instantiation of a container

Alternatively you could also login to the node where the pod was scheduled and use `docker ps` to get containarerid and `docker logs containarerid` to get logs.